# UX for upload many images on many folders

Tags: uploading-documents

I am having a problem about uploading many images to many folders, and have to identify each image (by code). I have 2 ideas for this.

Option 1: Set a name for each image and the user will choose the right image and upload it (like a photo)

[image]

Option 2: Let the user upload all photos at once and then select the images and identify them. as photo:
[image]
I'm wondering which option will bring a better experience and save time for users. And I don't know is there any better ux-optimal alternative? Looking forward to everyone's contributions.

Comment: Why do you need a specific order for the images? Please mention your requirements for a particular order.

Comment: What is the reason why image names are listed in a dropdown, and separated from the thumbnails?

Comment: @Sheraz : I need to know the exact name of an uploaded photo, These photos are required in one of our workflow. Based on that, our system can accurately warn users which photos are missing

Comment: @Izquierdo: This is an option that allows users to upload multiple photos and then name them to identify each image, we need to identify each image exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to come up with a logical solution if the context around the folders and images were clear.

As a generic solution, UI interactions and operations that relate to a many-to-many relationship is tricky because you might have many folders and just a few images (or vice versa) which is manageable, or worst case scenario you have many folders and many images which is not going to be easy to manage.

If you had to make a design and implementation decision, err on the side of caution and design for the most common scenario use case, and you'll at least reduce the complexity of the operation for a larger number of people.

Comment: Should I use A/B testing in this case?